# Is AngularJS useful for multi page applications

Tags: angularjs

I was reading about AngularJS basics, and like to use its binding feature in my pages. So I can define data that can be shown in view, can make changes in data so that it will be changed in view with no more worries.

In all examples I read, it starts with a template that acts as a skeleton for view, and a controller that fetch/update data so that it will be reflected in view.

I doubt if I can use this for a multi-page application. If my application includes different pages, each with different structure and purpose, is AngularJS a good option for me?

Comment: If you plan to retain your design like this 'If my application includes different pages, each with different structure and purpose', then I would say No. Having said that, it doesn't mean you can use AngularJS only for single page application. We use it instead of using say SpringMVC in front end or any other MVC or MVP frameworks. Offcourse you can use AngularJS for multi page applications, provided with a different design , using Angular JS components and concepts. Most of the applications are now using AngularJS in the front end, that are simply not single-page apps

Answer (score 1):

To achieve better user experience and/or meet expectations and requirements we are developing Single Page Applications and we do less of Multi-Page applications. When doing a SPA, Angular helps you develop testable code and helps you scale your development effort along other benefits.

When your application by nature have multiple pages, you can still benefit from using Angular for pages that you require to write client-side JavaScript code that you like to put in a MVC framework.

Because you can have multiple views and controllers in the same page, Angular can be used to create a multi-page effect too if the pages are somehow related like steps of a wizard.

But Angular or other JavaScript MVC Frameworks can be less useful on applications that are compromised of fairly isolated pages that each have limited client-side code. In these cases you should evaluate if you want to introduce the extra complexity that Angular may add.

AngularJS is adding to the amount of content that the browser has to download and running it can slow down some browsers on less capable hardwares.

Answer (score 1):

ya angularJs can be useful for multi page Applications and as well as for single page applications..you can use directives,factory  etc in your application

Comment: Really is that so,,can you please explain how can i use this for multipage

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create pages with different structure in AngularJS. You can wrap content of body inside `ng-view` and you specify different layouts for each page. This [blog](http://abhisheksarka.github.io/structuring-angular-with-rails) of my friend might help you learn more about structuring angular application.

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS can be useful for multi-page applications - the data-binding elements, directives, services, etc can still be used. The only thing that AngularJS DOESN'T handle is what any client-side framework doesn't handle: keeping data through page reloads.

You can also have multiple controllers - a controller for each page, if you want. Check out angular routing options (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Answer (score -1):

Rather go with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if you plan to do anything related to routing and layouts. Options there are rather limitless, just get it right.